# Set builder notation: defining the number of elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set *L* and I have a subset *S* which is part of *L* and contains three elements *A*, *B* and *C*. Finally, each of these elements are subsets that consist of their own elements:

$A=\{a_1...a_n\}$

$B=\{b_1...b_n\}$

$C=\{c_1...c_n\}$

*A*, *B* and *C* contain the same number of elements and those elements stand in a binary relation.

What I want to do is to specify that *A*, *B* and *C* consists of 'several' elements. 'Several' here means that there is at least one element and at most the number of elements which are smaller than *L*.

This is my attempt:

$S=\{x_ i | 1\le\ i\ \lt\ L\} $

where I use *x* to denote all elements from *A*, *B* and *C* and *i* to denote the number of elements.

I think that a link is missing here between the final representation and subsets *A*, *B* and *C*. Any suggestion how to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of elements of a set A, called *the cardinality of A* is denoted $|A|$. Here's what I understand you are trying to say:

I have a set $L$ and a set $S$ which is a subset of $L$. $S$ is the set $\{A, B, C\}$, where: $$A = \{a_1, a_2, ... a_n\}$$ $$B = \{b_1, b_2, ... b_n\}$$ $$C = \{c_1, c_2, ... c_n\}$$ for some integer $n$ such that $1 \le n \lt |L|$.